# What's the fastest way to implement a "follow us" functionality in iOS 4.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter, social-networking

I know iOS 5.0 has Twitter integration, but what's the fastest way to implement a "follow us" button in an iOS 4.0 compatible app?

Of course it is not a good idea to simply open a http://... to twitter in Safari because literally all users have their favorite Twitter client installed.

The best solution would be to display a list of installed twitter clients and let the user pick one. Then call openURL: of UIApplication with parameters for that particular client.

Maybe there's a open source framework or library which does just that?

Comment: The best solution would be to provide a button "Follow" which would perform the steps of 0Auth authorization and then follow operation.

Comment: I assume this involves a huge amount of classes right? Can you point out a tutorial or example of how complex this is?

Comment: There's this MGTwitterEngine. Then there's this OAuth Consumer in Objective-C at google code. It's not that hard, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps don't know what other apps are installed on a device, so this isn't possible. The best route would be to use a 3rd party Twitter API, such as [MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine), to create your own tool that will pop open a UIWebView or a custom control so that a user can follow you.

Comment: Wrong: You can query canOpenURL: with UIApplication to see if a favorite twitter client is installed. There are just a handful widespread twitter clients in use and it should be possible to check for them.

Comment: True; I've commented in your other question about this. You won't be able to list the other clients, however, unless you know their name and URL Scheme. canOpenURL doesn't provide any information about the other apps.

Comment: Agreed. True, if looking at it from that perspective.